# what caused druid tasks failed

Tags: apache-kafka, druid, segments

I had set up druid cluster(10 nodes),ingestion kafka data using **indexing service**.However,I found many of tasks are failed like below,but some data had been existed in segments,I am not sure if all datas are pushed in the segments.
[failed task lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOum7.jpg)

besides that,I choose some logs of failed tasks,found there are no  fatal error messages,I posted the log file, please help me what caused the task failed.thank so much.
[one log of failed tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZHWn.jpg)

there are 2 questions I want to ask,one is how to confirm all consumer data are pushed in the segments,the other is what caused the task Failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be the issue of Hadoop, where multiple threads trying to write to the same file at same time, you need to set `overwrite=false`

Check if you are running multiple ingestion tasks for same segments.

you can refer below link for further debugging it -

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/139150/no-lease-on-file-inode-5425306-file-does-not-exist.html